# 'latin-1' UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, encode

I'm trying to resolve this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(256) for this code snippet below

```
response = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?',
                            headers=header)
    res_j = response.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res_j)

    df.drop(df.tail(2).index, inplace=True)  # drop last n rows
    df = df.iloc[:, :-2]
    date_list = []
    price_list = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        date_list.append(index)
        price_list.append(row[0])
    # Lets plot bit coin price trend
    fig = px.line(x=date_list, y=price_list)
    fig.update_layout({"title": 'Bitcoin Price',
                       "xaxis": {"title": "Date"},
                       "yaxis": {"title": "Price"}})
    plotly_url = py.plot(fig, filename='Bitcoin-Price', auto_open=True)
    print("Plotly url : ", plotly_url)
    print("Head :", df.head())
    print("Tail :", df.tail())
```

Comment: show the traceback - which line does the error come from?

Comment: Last two tracebacks: ** File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\api\v2\utils.py:105 in get_headers
    plotly_auth = basic_auth(creds["username"], creds["api_key"])**

  **File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\api\utils.py:37 in basic_auth
    password = password.encode("latin1")**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Andrew if you add the traceback to the question you can format it more readably. Also it is useful skill to learn how to read them... each line is one layer of the "onion skin" of function calls that were being evaluated when the error occurred. So `basic_auth password = password.encode("latin1")` is where the error was raised, somewhere in a 3rd party library, then if you look through the other lines in the traceback there will be one from the code you have written. I think probably the line from your code is one that you haven't pasted into the question